# Not able to append html elements to el in backbone.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frameworks

I seem to have a problem with the code below. I have a div element with the id='content' in my html. I wanted to replace 'body' element of el property with the div element but my hello world text doesn't when I typed el: $('div') or el:$('div#content') or el: $('#content'). I'm a beginner in backbone.js and in my understanding, I believe that this el property holds our parent tag where all our templates will be added as child elements(in this case 'body' tag being parent and 'p' tag being child).

```
(function($){
    var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),      

    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        (this.el).append("<p>Hello World</p>");
    }
});

var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `View.el` property should be defined as a jQuery selector (string), not a reference to HTML element.

From [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

```
var BodyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: 'body'
});
```

Or as you wished,

```
el:'div#content'
```

When the view initializes, Backbone references the element in makes it available via the `view.$el`property, which is a cached jQuery object.

```
this.$el.append("<p>Hello World</p>");
```

The sample code you posted works, because there is always only one `body`element, and that element already exists in the DOM when your view is rendered. So when you declare `el:$('body')`, you get a reference to the body element. The code in `render`in works, because this.el is now a direct reference to the jQuery object:

```
(this.el).append("<p>Hello World</p>");
```

If you need to initialize a Backbone view using an existing DOM element (not a selector), Backbone documentation recommends passing it in the [initialize](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) function.

Comment: The funny thing is, my code (with div tag instead of body tag ) works in jsfiddle and not in my computer. On top of it, `this.$el.` is `undefined` when it selects the div tag.

Comment: @jaykumarark, you haven't posted a link to a jsfiddle, but my best guess is, that in jsfiddle the view is defined in the body.onload event handler (after DOM has been loaded), and therefore the element already exists.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/whcmU/4/ Thats the link. Seems like that code doesn't render the text in my div tag in my computer.

Comment: @jaykumarark, just as I guessed: If you change the load step from onLoad to "no wrap (head)" in the framework-selection of jsfiddle (top left side of screen), it won't work in jsfiddle either. That's because  DOM is not loaded when you try to acquire the reference to the element. Use the selector string as view.el and only initialize the view once DOM is loaded, it'll work. See: http://jsfiddle.net/A4MZs/

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that pointing out that obvious mistake. :) So stupid of me.